# Nvcc Optimization Flags

Tags: cuda, nvcc, compiler-flags

I have a CUDA c++ code.I'm doing some operations with OpenCV in this code.I compile program

```
  nvcc file.cu -o o2 `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4
```

command.I wonder that which nvcc optimization flags would be the best ,efficient and useful ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a .cpp and cuda file when I compile program with g++ file.cpp -o -fast , is faster than  nvcc file.cu -o o1 .So which optimization flag do you advice me to use for nvcc compiling?

Answer (score 1):

There is [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html) for `nvcc`.

There is also command-line help (`nvcc --help`).

You may find information about optimization and switches in either of those resources.

You shouldn't need any extra flags to get the fastest possible **device code** from `nvcc` (do not specify `-G`).   For host code optimization, you may wish to try `-O3`.